# How to configure multiple Redis DBs for multiple repositories on Spring-Data-Redis with @EnableRedisRepositories?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm creating 2 RespositoryConfigs with @EnableRedisRepositories and different RedisTemplate/redisTemplateRef references, however, it is always using only 1 DB.

Here some example (skipping the templates config which are using different RedisConnectionFactory and different RedisClient), and each package have only 1 repository A.class or B.class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.X.A",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = A.class),
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = B.class),
        redisTemplateRef = "templateA"
)
public class ARepositoryRedisConfig {

}
```

and

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.X.B",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = B.class),
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = A.class),
        redisTemplateRef = "templateB"
)
public class BRepositoryRedisConfig {

}
```

The repositories are CrudRepository.
Going a bit deeper, I see on registering the beans in:

> org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.RedisRepositoryConfigurationExtension#registerBeansForRoot

When registering the second repository I see it skips on: registerIfNotAlreadyRegistered because the first template is already registered.

Looking at other Spring-Data repository configs, it supposed to be supported.

Edit 1: How templates are configured

```
@Bean
public RedissonClient ARedissonClient(
        @Value("${A.redis.host}") String host,
        @Value("${A.redis.port}") String port,
        @Value("${diagnostic.app.name}") String appName,
        @Value("${redis.connectionPoolSize}") int connectionPoolSize,
        @Value("${redis.minimumIdleSize}") int connectionMinimumIdleSize,
        @Value("${redis.retryAttempts}") int retryAttempts,
        @Value("${redis.retryInterval}") int retryInterval,
        @Value("${A.redis.password:}") String password,
        @Value("${redis.timeout:6000}") int timeout,
        @Value("${redis.dns.monitoring.interval:5000}") int dnsMonitoringInterval
) {
...
}

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory ARedisConnectionFactory(RedissonClient ARedissonClient) {
    return new RedissonConnectionFactory(ARedissonClient);
}

@Bean(name = "templateA")
public RedisTemplate<String, String> templateA(RedisConnectionFactory ARedisConnectionFactory) {
...
}
```

And another one with templateB and different B.redis.host.
I tested calling the templates directly and both setups are fine, they are just not binding to the repositories, only 1 template is used for all repositories regardless what multiple EnableRedisRepositories defines.

Comment: Can you also share the code of the properties file where you have configured the data source for the two databases.

Comment: Wrote example of the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With great help from Redis support,they pointed it requires configuring and wiring keyValueTemplateRef as well, besides only redisTemplateRef.

So, configuration should look like:

```
@Bean(name = "templateA")
public RedisTemplate<String, String> templateA(RedisConnectionFactory ARedisConnectionFactory) {
...
}

@Bean(name = "templateKeyValueA")
public KeyValueTemplate templateKeyValueA(RedisTemplate templateA) {
        return new KeyValueTemplate(
                new RedisKeyValueAdapter(templateA),
                new RedisMappingContext()
        );
}

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.X.A",
        redisTemplateRef = "templateA",
        keyValueTemplateRef = "templateKeyValueA"
)
public class ARepositoryRedisConfig {

}
```

And same for BRepositoryRedisConfig and teamplateB.

Comment: I think there should be also `@Primary` annotation for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the data source configuration for the two databases have different property namespace.

```
//first database
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl = [URL]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]

//second database
spring.second-datasource.jdbcUrl = [URL]
spring.second-datasource.username = [username]
spring.second-datasource.password = [password]
```

Also if you have specified them in a properties file other than the application.properties make sure that you add `@PropertySource` annotation as well above your configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:your-custom-property-file.properties"})
@EnableRedisRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.X.A",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = A.class),
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = B.class),
        redisTemplateRef = "template"
)
public class ARepositoryRedisConfig {

}
```

On a different note, I think you do not have to add the include and exclude filters as the classes are in different packages.

Comment: _On a different note, I think you do not have to add the include and exclude filters as the classes are in different packages._

Yes, I know, I was just trying to "force" that only the repositories that I wanted were configured.

Answer (score 0):

I have such a sample with connecting 2 Redis to a single Spring application (with default Lettuce), it shows which beans and bean ref need to be wired.
https://github.com/alexvasseur/spring-twored

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).